# No matching client found for package name

Tags: android-studio

No matching client found for package name (getting package name with product flavor suffix)
manifest and google-service.json have same package name

Comment: This thread answers your problem in details: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374805/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-com-example-pc-fireapp