# No matching client found for package name 'com.example.pc.fireApp'

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, android-studio

I have this mistake when I sync my graddle. I think the problem comes from the google service.json file.

"No matching client found for package name 'com.example.pc.fireApp'".

My graddle :

```js
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pc.fireApp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you recently changed your package name in your app and your `google-services.json` file is not with that package

you have 2 options, first one is changing it manually

put your package "com.example.pc.fireApp" in all the places it requests `package_name`

```
Project - google-services.json file
```

[image]

[image]

option 2 is deleting it and connect again with firebase ( **Recommended since the first option will change the package at client side , it will work but you will see a different package in your firebase console and can lead to problems in the future** )

go to Tools in your IDE, Firebase and connect with any service , remember to delete google-services.json before

[image]

[image]